# Is it possible to use the aspnet-codegenerator to generate pages from multiple tables?

Tags: asp.net, razor

I would like to know if it is possible to get the apsnet-codegenerator to create the standard set of pages from multiple tables.

I.e. altering a table like below to do all tables and not just the groups table:

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator razorpage -m Groups -dc ThisContext -udl -    outDir Pages\Groups --referenceScriptLibraries
```

I can't seem to generate each pages from each table one by one due to the fact that after generating the first set of pages every attempt there after to generate pages from any other table results in the following error:

```
error CS0118: 'Groups' is a namespace but is used like a type
```

So if solving either of these problems is possible I would be very appreciative to hear how.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that Groups isn't an entity/class? Please post Groups-class.

Depending on your project-template be sure to add VS Codegeneration Design package.

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
```